# Secure a folder in a cluster

Tags: security, ubuntu-18.04, chmod, cluster, umask

I have a folder in a cluster that I want to secure by allowing access to me only (read, write and execute). I am new in using clusters, what are the command lines I can use?

I have used `umask u=rwx,g=,o=`, but once I logout, the permissions change. With `chmod` the permissions didn't change.

Comment: The term "cluster" is extremely vague. What cluster do you mean? Also, I strongly doubt that a directory's permissions change when you log out. Finally, it seems you have already found a solution, namely chmod. What is your problem?

Comment: a cluster is a machine in a server in which I am doing calculations. With umask I changed the permissions of my folder but once I logout the permissions was changed to the initial state. With chmod nothing has changed

Comment: "A machine in a server" doesn't make sense to me, but it doesn't seem to be relevant. With umask, you can't change permissions of existing folders. You change the initial permissions of *new* files and folders. Again, since chmod does set your folder's permissions, what is your problem?

Comment: chmod is not changing the permissions, I mean chmod is not working

Comment: If chmod can't change the directory's permissions, you may not have permission to change permissions, or the directory resides on a filesystem that doesn't have the permission concept such as FAT.